# Permission denied with make script even using sudo in /usr/local/include

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, sudo, make

I'm installing Sane (scanner software) and the make install script is attempting to create directories and move files to a new subdirectory in `/usr/local/include` but I keep getting a "Permission denied" error. I attempted running the make script even with sudo and it still gives me this error.

```
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/sane'
 /bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/include/sane’: Permission denied
```

I don't think it's a problem with sudo exactly, because I was able to `sudo mkdir /usr/local/include/sane` manually in a different terminal window, only when I attempted to run the make script again it now gets stuck on the next line, which is attempting to access files in this directory.

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644  sane/sane.h sane/saneopts.h '/usr/local/include/sane'
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/include/sane/sane.h': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/include/sane/saneopts.h': Permission denied
```

Is there some problem with sudo running make scripts? I was under the impression that sudo was the highest level access for Linux shell, but is there any higher access command I can use?

Comment: Compare the ownership and permissions of that folder you manually created with others around to be sure they are all alike! And also close and open the terminal and try again...

Comment: @George - Is this what the permissions should look like for this folder? `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  2 11:24 sane`  Also, I closed that terminal window and opened a new one, then ran the same command `sudo ./configure && make && make install` and still got the same "Permission denied" error.

Comment: There's something wrong with that file, can I have the link to the scanner so I can try to install

Comment: @George - Here's the download: https://alioth.debian.org/frs/download.php/file/4224/sane-backends-1.0.27.tar.gz

And here's the place where I got it from: http://www.sane-project.org/source.html

Comment: Ubuntu has `sane` in its repo will that do?

Comment: Well it will certainly be the end goal that I want, but this isn't a good problem to have if it persists with other activities. I'll try out the Ubuntu repo version and report back if the problem has been bypassed, and will open up a new question if I find this problem affecting other actions.

Comment: `sudo ./configure && make && make install` means that only `configure` is run with `sudo`. The other two commands aren't.

Comment: @muru - Ok, that was the problem! It seems to work correctly now when I break it into 3 separate commands. Could you make an answer of this? Then I can select it. Huh, one would think that the `sudo` would carry over. Is there a way to do a string of commands and keep the elevated permissions?

Comment: My first guess would be `sudo ./configure && sudo make && sudo make install`.

Comment: `./configure` and `make` should never have to be run with `sudo`. Only `make install` should need `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a suggestion from one of the commenters (muru), my problem was that `sudo ./configure && make && make install` only gives `sudo` elevated permissions to the first command, i.e. `./configure`, so I ran `sudo ./configure` and `sudo make` and `sudo make install` separately, and then I was able to successfully install without errors.